# How to create a gap above navigation bar where we place text or buttons in bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, html, navigation, bootstrap-4

I want to create a gap above navigation bar for echo name like: Welcome Sarah! Kindly check the image what output I am getting:

[image]

1. In above image I want to echo Welcome Sarah above the Login | Sign Up buttons.
2. I want to show search bar above the Adidad Shoe Store Starting from let-top. And welcome Sarah on the right-end. Then navigation will show.

my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div class="container">
 <div class="row float-right" >

  // Search bar
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
 <a href="">Hello Sarah!</a>
 </div>
 </div>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Adidas Shoe Store</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb" aria-expanded="true">
 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <div id="navb" class="navbar-collapse collapse hide">
<ul class="navbar-nav">



  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:#007bff;">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 2</a>
  </li>
  </ul>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fas fa-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></span> Login</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not working as expected because Bootstrap `.fixed-top` class assigns `z-index` value of `1030` and `position:fixed` at top to the `nav`.

As a result, the `.container` you added is displayed both behind and not above the `nav`.

The `.container` needs `position` other than `static` and `z-index` greater than `1030` to display above the `nav`. Additionally, the `nav` needs some `padding-top` to make visual space for the `.container` contents in this scenario.

The following structure and added CSS achieves the effect you're looking for:

```
<div class="container" style="position: relative; z-index: 1031; padding: .5rem 1rem;">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
     </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
      <a href="">Hello Sarah!</a>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light" style="padding-top: 2.5rem">
```

(I've thrown in two `.col-sm-6` divs inside your `.row` to make things easier to arrange on mobile resolutions; also note that `.container` class is of limited width unlike `nav` so you should change it to `.container-fluid`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer just awesome. What a great explanation. I have applied your code, my navigation bar come down now but search bar and welcome sarah! are showing on the navbar now, not above the navbar. Before both are showing below the navbar.

Comment: Glad to hear! Interesting - should work as expected. Take a look at this pen to figure out what's causing the issue: https://codepen.io/pgalor/pen/cd68b3d3af00fba26f8bc8dd3503e2c7